# PHP fwrite(); Creates Extra Characters

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a PHP script that retrieves variables via `$_POST`, and modifies another PHP file with said variables. However, whenever the script is run the last 12 characters of the file to be modified are copied and concatenated to the end of the file.

The file I am trying to modify is called **database_info.php** and is as follows;

```
<?php
/**
 * These are the database login details
 */  
define("HOST", "{HOST}");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "{USER}");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "{PASSWORD}");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "{DATABASE}");    // The database name.

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

This is my PHP script that modifies database_info.php

```
<?php

$host = $_POST['DBhost'];
$name = $_POST['DBname'];
$user = $_POST['DBuser'];
$pass = $_POST['DBpassword'];

echo "<p> Hostname: ", $host ,"</p></br>";
echo "<p> Database: ",$name, "</p></br>";
echo "<p> User: ", $user, "</p></br>";
echo "<p> User: ", $pass , "</p></br>";

$search = array('{HOST}','{USER}','{PASSWORD}','{DATABASE}');
$replace = array($host,  $user, $pass, $name);
$file = file_get_contents("database_info.php");
$fh = fopen("database_info.php", 'c');
$file = str_replace($search, $replace, $file);
fwrite($fh, $file);
fclose($fh);

include 'functions.php';
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE); //create connection, store to variable "con"

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Create a table
$sql="CREATE TABLE canvas(name CHAR(30),content CHAR(30))";

// Check if table was created
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
{
    echo "Table created successfully";
} 

else 
{
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

When the PHP script is run with the `$_POST` variables

```
$host = localhost;
$name = CMS;
$user = root;
$pass = root;
```

database_info.php changes into

```
<?php
/**
 * These are the database login details
 */  
define("HOST", "localhost");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "root");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "CMS");    // The database name.

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);| E_STRICT);
```

the problem is on the last line, `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);| E_STRICT);` The last 12 characters (`| E_STRICT);`) have been concatenated to the end are causing a syntax error. I can fix the problem by adding 12 extra commented characters to the end of the file so it only copies commented characters, but that is an unelegant solution and does not address the problem.

I've noticed that the variables added to database_info.php make it 12 characters shorter than the original, is this the problem? I think the problem is stemming from `fwrite()`, but I am not entirely sure. Does anyone know why my script is adding these extra characters?

Comment: Why not use `file_get_contents()` / `file_put_contents()` ?

Comment: And also, your issue is that the `error_reporting` part (`| E_STRICT`) is getting added to the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in statement `fopen()`

If you read documentation of `fopen` you are using parameter `c` for opening file, which doesn't truncate existing file, but just put the file pointer at beginning of file. Now, since your `POST` values 12 character short to your `{..}` values it doesn't "overwrite" the last 12 character, but otherwise just replace everything with new string.

Simple solution is use `w` in your `fopen` always. So

```
$fh = fopen("database_info.php", 'c');
$file = file_get_contents("database_info.php");
```

will become

```
$file = file_get_contents("database_info.php");
$fh = fopen("database_info.php", 'w');
```

if you use `file_get_contents` after opening file for write, you will get empty file to read

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention you should use fopen after the "file_get_Content" statement, just swap them.